# qUncompress: Z_DATA_ERROR: Input data is corrupted

Tags: qt, zlib, compression

I am using the qUncompress of Qt and head to a problem I cant find more information to solve it. 
Here is my code:

```
    #include <QCoreApplication>
    #include <QByteArray>
    #include <QFile>
    #include <QDebug>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        QFile f("/user/XXXXX/home/AgeRegression"); // hided
        if (f.exists())
            qDebug() << "File exists";
        else
            qDebug() << "Missing file";
        f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        QByteArray qb = f.readAll();
        qb = qUncompress(qb);
        qDebug()<<"Successfully";
        const char *qt_version = qVersion();
        qDebug()<< QString(qt_version);
        return a.exec();
     }
```

Here is the output:

```
     File exists
     qUncompress: Z_DATA_ERROR: Input data is corrupted
     Successfully
     "5.3.2"
```

From the documentation of Qt(you can find [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qUncompress)):

> Note: If you want to use this function to uncompress external data that was compressed using zlib, you first need to prepend a four byte header to the byte array containing the data. The header must contain the expected length (in bytes) of the uncompressed data, expressed as an unsigned, big-endian, 32-bit integer.

So what exactly should I do here? Do I have to find the length of uncompressed data (is there a way? I just have compressed data.)? An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`qUncompress` is not a general-purpose decompression function. It should only be used with data compressed with `qCompress`.

If your data was compressed using something other than `qCompress`, you must decompress it in the same way - using zlib directly, using an external utility, etc.

By using `qUncompress` like you do, you're relying on an implementation detail that may change at any moment. Don't do that. Simply assume that `qCompress` is a black box and uses an alien compressor implementation that nobody else does.

Comment: I know that can be dangerous and your way is of course safer. But this code is just for the test for the problem I face when try to test one library. Thanks. :)